# 'Things such as something' vs. 'such things as something'

Tags: differences, adverbs, conjunctions, quantifiers

The original one: 1. From the view point of **outstanding teachers such as John...**

2. From the view point of **such outstanding teachers as John ...**
3. From the view point of **outstanding teachers such John as...**

Do they mean the same? if no, would you please change the *order* of the words -without change any of the words in the bold parts- in such a way that they mean the same thing?

Comment: The last one is just ungrammatical.  The first and second are not the same and can only be made the same by putting them in the same word order.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 do not mean the same.

3 ("outstanding teachers such John as") does not make sense.

In 2, using "such" before "outstanding" adds emphasis to it.

Then in 1, when you use "teachers as John..." you are using "as" to begin a list of examples.
It's almost a short form of "such as". It would be better to use "such as" again or "like".

You are asking us to change the order of the non-bold words to make the words mean the same thing, but unfortunately 3 will never make any sense due to its bolded words.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that 1 and 2 differ slightly in what is being stated.

1 ("Outstanding teachers such as John") means the viewpoint is shared by all outstanding teachers, of which John is one example.

2 ("Such outstanding teachers as John") means only those teachers who are outstanding in the same way that John is outstanding.

I could be wrong...

Comment: I think that (2) would be rarely used; it sounds rarefied. 'Only teachers of John's calibre' or 'Only teachers as good as John' would be more idiomatic.